# How to fix 'dynamic' property 'IpfSetId' must also be '@objc'?

Tags: swift, realm

I wrote a code months ago for my realm model and it works well. but now I get an error on  `RealmOptional` properties that says `'dynamic' property 'IpfSetId' must also be '@objc'`

I Update, clean and rebuild RealmSwift pod but it doesn’t help me

```swift
@objcMembers class InspectionPointFields: Object {
    dynamic var IpfId: Int = 0
    dynamic var IpfGuid: String?
    dynamic var IpfFieldName: String?
    dynamic var IpfFieldType: Int = 0
    dynamic var IpfSetId = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var IpfComponentCustomInput: String?


    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "IpfId"
    }
    convenience init(IpfId: Int,IpfGuid: String?,
                     IpfFieldName: String?,IpfFieldType: Int,IpfSetId: Int?, IpfComponentCustomInput: String?) {
        self.init()
        self.IpfId = IpfId
        self.IpfGuid = IpfGuid
        self.IpfFieldName = IpfFieldName
        self.IpfFieldType = IpfFieldType
        self.IpfSetId.value = IpfSetId
        self.IpfComponentCustomInput = IpfComponentCustomInput


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional Ints are achieved with the `RealmOptional` type as  you've correctly identified. Primitives though use constant optionals. I.e. replace your declaration of:-

```
dynamic var IpfSetId = RealmOptional<Int>()
```

with

```
let IpfSetId = RealmOptional<Int>()
```